# reactjs bundle.js produce findindex which cannot run in Internet Explore 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I was facing problem when I used findIndex() to match string. But in Internet Explore it cause issue. So plan to remove findIndex. Now, I did not used findindex or includes in my reactjs code. I am creating bundle.js file in which, I can find findIndex method which is not supported in Internet Explore 11.

**I don't know how to remove findIndex() from bundle.js**

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'findIndex'
bundle.js
```

Comment: Try @babel/polyfill  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Comment: @Atul Still Yeah It works..Thank you a-lot. I install babel-polyfill package and imported to my main app.js on the top of the file.